# Neo4j - Error when having the data folder on external hard drive

Tags: database, macos, neo4j

I can start Neo4j without issues using default settings.

Now I try to have my Neo4j data in a folder of an external hard drive because I don't have enough space on my local machine for an import. 
So in my neo4j.conf I have set: `dbms.directories.data=/Volumes/INTENSO/richRich/neo4j-data`. Then on `neo4j start` a `databases` folder gets created, but the database shuts down immediately after start. This is what I perceived as useful from the debug.log stacktrace:

```
...

2018-07-22 11:25:55.745+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] --- INITIALIZED diagnostics END ---
2018-07-22 11:25:55.912+0000 INFO [o.n.b.BoltKernelExtension] Bolt Server extension loaded.
2018-07-22 11:25:56.069+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.s.f.RecordFormatSelector] Selected format 'RecordFormat:StandardV3_4[v0.A.9]' for the new store
2018-07-22 11:25:56.118+0000 WARN [o.n.k.NeoStoreDataSource] Exception occurred while setting up store modules. Attempting to close things down. Unable to open store file: /Volumes/INTENSO/richRich/neo4j-data/databases/graph.db/neostore.nodestore.db.labels
org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.UnderlyingStorageException: Unable to open store file: /Volumes/INTENSO/richRich/neo4j-data/databases/graph.db/neostore.nodestore.db.labels

...

Caused by: org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.FileLockException: Already locked: /Volumes/INTENSO/richRich/neo4j-data/databases/graph.db/neostore.nodestore.db.labels

...
```

I checked `/Volumes/INTENSO/richRich/neo4j-data/databases/graph.db/neostore.nodestore.db.labels` and the file is there. I also made everything chmod -R 777 to ensure that there are no permission issues.

OS: latest MacOS
Neo4j: 3.4.4 Community Edition

Comment: Hey, were you able to find the solution?

Comment: Hi @BharatChhabra, unfortunately no

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but I had the same issue today and fixed it by reformatting my external drive to the APFS format and that resolved the issue.